# Multi Word User Input Compared to a Variable in Batch

Tags: input, batch-file, comparison

Im having some trouble with comparing a multi word string input by the user with a string variable in Batch. This is what I have:

```
    set twowordstring=Pi Rocks
    echo What do you think about Pi?    
    set /p response=
    if %response% EQU %twowordstring% goto correct
```

When ran the cmd just closes, but I caught a glimpse of the error message. I think the set /p is only collecting the second word of the two word input. Please help, am I setting up the input wrong or is there a different command to collect the entire line?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `IF` statement is causing the problem.

The syntax is `if string equ string dosomething`

Since you have a space in both your response and the string against which you're making the comparison, the processor sees

```
if Pi Rocks equ Pi Rocks goto correct
```

and expects a comparison operator like `equ` after the first string, so objects to `Rocks` and responds `Rocks was unexpected at this time`

To correct, simply enclose the arguments in quotes

```
if "%response%" equ "%twowordsstring%" goto correct
```

You could aso change `if` to `if /i` to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Also, placing a

```
pause
```

at a strategic point will prevent the window from closing.